# Play mms:// streams on my site

Tags: javascript, flash, streaming, mms, windows-media-server

I'm building a "channel chooser" for a set of [mms:// streams (Microsoft Media Server)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server): a simple web GUI that lets the user chose which channel to listen to. For reference, here is [the list of streams](http://www.sr.se/sida/artikel.aspx?ProgramId=2321&Artikel=787720) I'd like to use. I would like users to be able to play those streams on my site with a simple "play/stop" control. Nothing fancy.

How should I attack this? Any ideas or pointers appreciated! New angles and hacks around the problem too.

Javascript or Flash players are of course preferable, but I haven't been able to find any player that plays mms:// streams. My back-end language is Django if that helps anyone get any ideas.

Comment: A solution that can be made to work on both Windows, Mac, and Linux is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMS will require the user to have Windows Media Player installed.  I believe you can embed mms:// content directly in an HTML page using `<object>` and/or `<embed>` tags and if it's installed, the WMP browser plugin will play the content.

Here's an [Embedded Media HTML Generator](http://cit.ucsf.edu/embedmedia/step2.php?mediatype=WindowsMedia); enter your mms:// url here and use the generated HTML in your video player page template.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. Is it possible to install Windows Media Player on Mac and Linux boxes?

Comment: I believe the cross-platform VLC media player has a browser plugin that will support streaming Windows Media. (I could be wrong; check http://www.videolan.org/vlc/ for details)